# Constructor for array of variable size

Tags: java, arrays, constructor

I want to code a constructor for an array of size x with x being a parameter speciified in main().
My class:

```
public class CharA
{
  private char[] stack;
  private int n = 0;

  public void CharA (int max)
  {
    this.stack = new char[max];
    this.n = max;
  }
```

My main():

```
public class CharTest
{
  public static void main (String args)
  {
    CharA stack1 = new CharA(100);
  }
}
```

The error:

```
CharTest.java:5: cannot find symbol
symbol  : constructor CharA(int)
location: class CharA
    CharA stack1 = new CharA(100);
                   ^
```

There are several examples here where the same thing is done with an int array. Why doesn't it work for this char array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

remove `void` in your "constructor":

```
public CharA (int max) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: @Marv: It happens to the best :)

Answer (score 4):

Replace `public void CharA (int max)` with `public CharA (int max)`, because constructors don't have a return type.

Answer (score 2):

The constructor method should not have a return type in its definition:

```
public CharA(int max) {...}
```