# How do I set a constructor's parameters to an array of variable size?

Tags: c#, arrays, parameters, constructor

HOMEWORK: We're working on a hangman program. I have the following method:

```
    public char[] selectWord()
    {
        String[] hangmanWords = new String[50] { "time", "person", "year", "way", "day", "thing", "man", "world", "life", "hand", "part", "child", "eye", "woman", "place", "work", "week", "case", "point", "government", "company", "number", "group", "problem", "fact", "good", "new", "first", "last", "long", "great", "little", "own", "other", "old", "right", "big", "high", "different", "small", "large", "next", "early", "young", "important", "few", "public", "bad", "same", "able" };
        Random wordIndex = new Random();
        int randomIndex = wordIndex.Next(0, 49); 
        wordToGuess = hangmanWords[randomIndex].ToUpper();
        char[] wordToGuessArray = wordToGuess.ToCharArray();                                         // convert word to array of letters
        return wordToGuessArray;  
    }
```

I would like to define a constructor for `wordToGuessArray`. Ideally I want the `selectWord()` method to set the `wordToGuessArray` parameter. However, I won't know the variable array length until after I run this method and I can't create a constructor without explicitly defining `char[x]`. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8918660/constructor-for-array-of-variable-size) has the array length set in main. Mine cannot due to requirements restrictions in the assignment. So where would this `selectWord()` method need to live in order to properly `set` my variable?

I'm having a hard time picturing a workable program flow for that.

Comment: It's unclear what you want, partly because your terminology is confused ("create a constructor" might mean "declare a variable"?).  Can you show how you would like your code to look when you're done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're somewhat confused. `char[] wordToGuessArray = wordToGuess.ToCharArray();` is not only allocating the correct size array for you, it's also filling it with the contents of `wordToGuess` I have two suggested changes to make your code better.

```
public char[] selectWord()
{
    // get rid of size in this, when you do static init you don't need it
    String[] hangmanWords = new String[] { "time", "person", "year", "way", "day", "thing", "man", "world", "life", "hand", "part", "child", "eye", "woman", "place", "work", "week", "case", "point", "government", "company", "number", "group", "problem", "fact", "good", "new", "first", "last", "long", "great", "little", "own", "other", "old", "right", "big", "high", "different", "small", "large", "next", "early", "young", "important", "few", "public", "bad", "same", "able" };
    // combinme those bottom 5 or so lines into 1.
    return hangmanWords[new Random.Next(0, 49)].ToUpper().ToCharArray();
}
```

This method will simply return a character array which has the characters of a randomly selected word from the `hangmanWords` array. I believe that's what you want, right?

If you want the character array `wordToGuessArray` to be a property of your class then just declare it as `public char[] wordsToGuessArray { get; set; }` and make the method void, replacing the return with assingment to wordsToGuessArray.

Sample constructor;

```
 // field declared in my class, call it game
 public char[] wordsToGuessArray { get; set; }

 public Game(char[] word)
 {
       wordToGuessArray = word;
 }
 // call it like this
 Game game = new Game(selectWord());
```

If you want to set `wordToGuessArray` in the constructor you can make `selectWord()` a `public static` method in the same class in which case you would call it like `Game.selectWord()`

Comment: Yes, but I'm trying to pass the randomly chosen word to a constructor so I can recall it from any class in my project. I can't set the constructor and its parameters unless I've got the array length, right?

Comment: Oh I think I now what you mean. I'll edit with a sample constructor. You don't have to know the array length.

Answer (score 1):

you may looking for the [param](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) keyword. It allows you to pass an undefind numbers of parameters to a Constructor like this example shows:

```
public static void UseParams2(params object[] list) 
{
   for ( int i = 0 ; i < list.Length ; i++ )
      Console.WriteLine(list[i]);
   Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Relegated to your post, your code could look like this:

```
public char[] selectWord(params string[] hangmanWords)
{
    Random wordIndex = new Random();
    int randomIndex = wordIndex.Next(0, hangmanWords.Count()); 
    wordToGuess = hangmanWords[randomIndex].ToUpper();
    char[] wordToGuessArray = wordToGuess.ToCharArray();                                         // convert word to array of letters
    return wordToGuessArray;  
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP wants, not sure though.

Comment: me too i more or less guessing, its a just a try if its not what he wanted its still does not hurt anyone ;-)